# How to Use Scanner close in this Prorgram?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;                      //Scanner is imported here
public class Reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rev=0, rem;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);        //Scanner is used here and error is shown in this line
    System.out.println("Enter a number ");
    int a=s.nextInt();
    int b=a;
    
    while(b!=0)
    {
    rem=b%10;
    rev=rev*10+rem;
    b=b/10;
    }
    
    System.out.println("The reverse of the number is " +rev);
    
    if(a==rev)
    {
        System.out.println("The number is Palindrome.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The number is not Palindrome");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it mandatory to close a Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976492/is-it-mandatory-to-close-a-scanner)

Comment: `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner is used here and error is shown in this line` It's not an error, it's a warning, since class [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) implements interface [java.io.Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html) and it's your IDE trying to help you but in this case you should ignore your IDE's advice.

Answer (score 1):

use `s.close();` at the end within main function.

Your program will look like this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int rev=0, rem;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);        //Scanner is used here and error is shown in this line
System.out.println("Enter a number ");
int a=s.nextInt();
int b=a;

while(b!=0)
{
rem=b%10;
rev=rev*10+rem;
b=b/10;
}

System.out.println("The reverse of the number is " +rev);

if(a==rev)
{
    System.out.println("The number is Palindrome.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("The number is not Palindrome");
}

s.close();                        //SCANNER ENDS HERE.
```